# Drawing the X and y axis for a curved Line in C# Form

Tags: c#, axis-labels

[image: X and Y axis To point out my graph]   [image: My Curved Line]
i i am relative new to c# and is trying to draw a curved line in c#. I would like to ask that is there any possible way to create an X and Y axis in order to show the coordinates of each point of the curved line. 
 Please do help me on this matter as i am stuck on how to execute it.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {


        float a = 1, b = 5, c = 1;
        double x1, x2, x3,x4,x5,x6, y1, y2, y3,y4,y5, delta;
        delta = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);

        x1=0;
        y1 = a * (x1 * x1) + (b * (x1)) + c;
        x2 =  3;
        y2 = a * (x2 * x2) + (b * (x2)) + c;
        x3 = - 3;
        y3 = a * (x3 * x3) + (b * (x3)) + c;
        x4 = 5;
        y4 = a * (x4 * x4) + (b * (x4)) + c;
        x5 = -10;
        y5 = a * (x5 * x5) + (b * (x5)) + c;
        int cx1 = Convert.ToInt32(x1);
        int cx2 = Convert.ToInt32(x2);
        int cx3 = Convert.ToInt32(x3);
        int cy1 = Convert.ToInt32(y1);
        int cy2 = Convert.ToInt32(y2);
        int cy3 = Convert.ToInt32(y3);
        int cx4 = Convert.ToInt32(x4);
        int cy4 = Convert.ToInt32(y4);
        int cx5 = Convert.ToInt32(x5);
        int cy5 = Convert.ToInt32(y5);
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        int deltaX = 100;
        int deltaY = 100;
        g.TranslateTransform(deltaX, deltaY);
        float factor = 2.5f;
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.Scale(factor, factor);
        g.MultiplyTransform(m);
        Pen aPen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 1);
        Point point1 = new Point(cx1, cy1);
        Point point2 = new Point(cx2, cy2);
        Point point3 = new Point(cx3, cy3);
        Point point4 = new Point(cx4, cy4);
        Point point5 = new Point(cx5, cy5);


        Point[] Points = {  point5, point3, point1,point2,point4 };
        g.DrawCurve(aPen, Points);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand you, but it sounds like you want to make your GDI+ graphics scale with the window size (i.e. you want to scale the X and Y axis with the size of the window), right?

This is pretty simple, you just have to decide how big of a space you want to present in the window -- i.e. if you want to make the axis go from 0,0 on the top left, to 512x512 on the bottom right, then you would just need to scale the X axis by a factor of 512/width, and the Y axis by a factor of 512/height.

So you would do that by performing a [ScaleTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhc2xxtx(v=vs.110).aspx) on your [Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) object.  You'll need to use your [Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx)'s [ClientSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9278sfx2.aspx) to get the width and height.  (The regular Form's .Width, and .Height properties, include all the borders and title bars, padding pixels, etc. -- so it's no good for this calculation.)

Then you will need to force an [Invalidation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz8ytzt0.aspx) during the form's [Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize.aspx) event (it will work without this, when you make the window smaller, but when you make it bigger, this will be required, or else it will only redraw the edges).

Another thing worth considering is turning on the form's [DoubleBuffered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered.aspx) property, the redraw will be much smoother.

So, let's assume you want to work in a virtual space of 512x512 "pixels" where 0 ,0 is always the top left, and 512,512 is the bottom right.  You could add this code to the top of your OnPaint event handler:

```
float scaleX = 512f / ((float)this.ClientSize.Width);
float scaleY = 512f / ((float)this.ClientSize.Height);
e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scaleX, scaleY);
```

Then add a handler for the Form's [Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize.aspx) event and add something like this:

```
this.Invalidate(true);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: I Appreciate your time and effort for helping me solve this. Although i actually wanted to draw X and Y Line(Example Pic Uploaded) in order to show the points of the coordinate in my curved Line. Do you have any thoughts on this as well? 
 Thank you again for your help.

Comment: This approach to scaling will work regardless of the drawing operation. `g.DrawCurve(aPen, Points);` should continue to work, assuming the point coordinates are within your virtual space (in my example that means X & Y of each point is between 0 x 0 and 512 x 512).